# How to check for the same column value on next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that gives me data regarding the journey of a proposal. A proposal may hit different statuses, which are then mapped to a milestone. A status may be hit more than once in succession, but we don't want the milestone to repeat.

| ID | MilestoneID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |

So in the example above, this would be a problem. How can I write a query that tells me if a milestone ID is the same on the next row in the journey table?

```
SELECT ID, MilestoneID, count(*) as vol
FROM Journey
GROUP BY ID, MilestoneID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

The above code tells me that we have instances where the Milestone is repeated, but I need to know if they are on successive rows.

Comment: Have you had a look at `LAG`/`LEAD`?

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER()` can be of use.

```
with milestone as ( 
    select 1 Id, 1 MilestoneId 
    union all 
    select 1 Id, 2 MilestoneId 
    union all 
    select 1 Id, 3 MilestoneId 
    union all 
    select 1 Id, 3 MilestoneId 
) 
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MilestoneId ORDER BY MilestoneId ASC) > 1 THEN 'Same Milestone Id' 
            ELSE NULL 
       END Status 
FROM milestone
```

[Check Same Milestone Ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4JGd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using `lead()` function :

First, we need to create an id for each record; if you already have a unique id, you can skip this CTE.

Cte2 will check to see if two successif rows are equal, and if they are, we will use the having clause `having sum(next_value) > 0` to get it.

```
with cte as (
  select ID, MilestoneID, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
  from Journey
),
cte2 as (
  select *,
     lead(MilestoneID) over (partition by ID order by rn) as lead_val,
     CASE WHEN MilestoneID = lead(MilestoneID) over (partition by ID order by rn) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as next_value
  from cte
)
select ID, MilestoneID
from cte2
group by ID, MilestoneID
having sum(next_value) > 0
```

Result :

```
ID  MilestoneID
1   3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9oHFUoKt)

Answer (score -1):

Use ROW_NUMBER(),

```
Select ID, MilestoneID 
From ( 
      Select ID, MilestoneID, RN=Row_Number()  over(PARTITION BY ID, MilestoneID ORDER BY MilestoneID ) 
      FROM Journey )X
Where X.RN=2
```